# Prevent Firefox from thinking images are downloads

Tags: firefox

When I save an image in Firefox it opens up the download window (just once after boot) and from thereon any image also saved using Firefox appears in the download window.
Is there any way to exclude them so they don't clog up the download window?

Answer (score 3):

To do so, follow below steps:

1. Press Alt+T and click on Option.
2. Option dialog box will appear, Click on General tab.
3. In Download section, Uncheck 'Show the Download's window when downloading a file' option.
4. On the 'Always ask me where to save files' radio button.
5. Click on OK button to save your Preferences.

Comment: This doesn't prevent the item from showing in the download window though right?... it just prevents the download window from showing?

Answer (score 2):

If you download something, it will be shown in Download Window. Exclusion is not possible AFAIK! However, you can delete those items from download window and leave only what you want to see on this window.

By the way, choosing where to save downloaded file doesn't prevent it from appearing in download window.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the server that delivers the file attaches a **Mime Type** to detect the image as a download which forces the browser program to interpret the image file as a file download.

But my Firefox 17 automatically displays the images inline. Please update your Firefox to latest version and check.

**Update:**

While saving the image from a web page using **Save As** option, it works as a download. AFAIK, there's no way to exclude it from download list.

But you can try drag and drop. Just drag the image from webpage and drop it to your Desktop or some location. The image will be saved to the location.

Answer (score 1):

This extension worked for me: [InlineDisposition](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition/?src=search)

quoting the addon page:

> InlineDisposition changes the disposition type of Content-Disposition response headers from attachment to inline; this prevents servers from forcing the browser to save a file and allows that file to be viewed in the browser, if the browser supports it.